# Use action with selector in UIAction for menus in UIKit

Tags: swift, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uikit

Im trying to use action in the UIAction for my menu item in UIKit. So, For first button Im not able to apply action. It shows me error "Cannot find 'action' in scope"

I really want to use selector in this case. I want to know what's perfect way to take action on the selector

```
 class MessageViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    
        private lazy var first = UIAction(title: "Edit", image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil.circle"), attributes: [], state: .off) { [self]_ in
        action:  #selector(self.RightSideBarButtonItemTapped(_:))
    
        }
        private lazy var second = UIAction(title: "Second", image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil.circle"), attributes: [.destructive], state: .on) { action in
            print("Second")
            #selector(self.sendMessageRightSideBarButtonItemTapped(_:))
        }
        
        private lazy var third = UIAction(title: "Third", image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil.circle"), attributes: [], state: .off) { action in
            print("third")
        }
    
        private lazy var elements: [UIAction] = [first]
        private lazy var menu = UIMenu(title: "new", children: elements)
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    
     view.backgroundColor = .white
                    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: nil)
                    menu = menu.replacingChildren([first, second, third])
                    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.menu = menu
                    }
    }
```

Tried Solution from @Hangar Rash

```
       private lazy var first = UIAction(title: "Edit", image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil.circle"), attributes: [], state: .off)
        { [unowned self] action in
            self.RightSideBarButtonItemTapped(_:)
    // Getting error on this line which says its " Function is unused "
            
        }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {}

        @objc func RightSideBarButtonItemTapped(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem!)
        {
            let vc = IceWorldView()
                present(vc, animated: true)
        }
```

Comment: The `UIAction` for `first` has a typo. Make it like the other two.

Comment: ` private lazy var first = UIAction(title: "First", image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil.circle"), attributes: [.destructive], state: .on) { action in
            print("First")
            #selector(self.sendMessageRightSideBarButtonItemTapped(_:))
        }`

Comment: This doesn't work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first action has two issues:

1. a syntax error with `action`
2. there's no need to use `#selector`. Just call the method directly

Change:

```
private lazy var first = UIAction(title: "Edit", image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil.circle"), attributes: [], state: .off) { [self]_ in
    action:  #selector(self.RightSideBarButtonItemTapped(_:))
}
```

to:

```
private lazy var first = UIAction(title: "Edit", image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil.circle"), attributes: [], state: .off) { [unowned self] action in
    self.RightSideBarButtonItemTapped(someButton)
}
```

Your `RightSideBarButtonItemTapped` expects a `UIBarButtonItem` parameter but you don't have one in the menu. You can either made a dummy button instance to pass in or you can change the `RightSideBarButtonItemTapped` so it doesn't take any parameters. You don't seem to use the passed in sender anyway.

Fix the use of `#selector` in your second action as well.

Comment: Use same syntax by you. Getting error for function. Function is unused

Comment: Edit your question by adding your latest attempt to the end of the question and show the exact error.

Comment: I have modified the question which says about your solution

Comment: As I said you need to call the `self.RightSideBarButtonItemTapped` method just like you would if you were calling it from anywhere else. This means the parentheses must contain the proper parameter values that the method expects.

Comment: I just updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks for updating one more time. Tried your solution but giving other error. Error `Cannot convert value of type 'UIButton?' to expected argument type 'UIBarButtonItem?'`

Comment: You need to pass in an instance of a `UIBarButtonItem`, not ` UIButton`.

Comment: Is that you mean `let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.forward.circle.fill") , style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(RightSideBarButtonItemTapped(:_)))` then pass like this `self.RightSideBarButtonItemTapped(_:button1)`

Comment: Not working above suggestion

Comment: Thanks @HangarRash I was able to do it. Now, Im calling self.RightSideBarButtonItemTapped(). You're great man